# Number of arrangements of $8$ children of different ages in a line if none of the three youngest children stand next to each other

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

Eight children of different ages stand in a random order in a line. Find the number of different ways can be done if none of the three youngest children stand next to each other.

This question was taken from Maths 9709 A Level Paper 61 May/June 2017.

In the marking scheme, it was written that:

Total - $3$ together - $2$ together = $8! - 6!3! - 6! \cdot 2 \cdot  5 \cdot 3 = 14400$

Can anyone clarify for me how does $6! \cdot 2 \cdot 5 \cdot 3$ made up?

Comment: We are not selecting a subset here, so this is not a combinations problem. An arrangement of distinct objects is a permutation problem.  The study of arrangements falls under the more general heading of combinatorics.

Comment: Please read this [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Answer (score 1):

Let's consider what the terms count.

The term $8!$ counts all arrangements of the eight children.

The term $6!3!$ counts all arrangements of the eight children in which all three of the youngest children are together.  To see this, observe that if we treat the block of the three youngest children as a block, we have six objects to arrange, the block and the other five children.  Those six objects can be arranged in $6!$ ways.  The three youngest children can be arranged within the block in $3!$ ways.  Hence, there are $6!3!$ arrangements in which the three youngest children are all together.

Since we must also exclude those arrangements in which exactly two of the three youngest children are together, the final term must count those arrangements.  To count them, we consider two cases, depending on whether the two children who are together are at one of the ends or not.

*Exactly two of the three youngest children are together at one of the ends*:  There are $\binom{3}{2}$ ways to choose which two of the three youngest children are together.  There are two ways to choose which end of the line they are at.  There are two ways to arrange the selected children within their block.  There are five ways to choose the position of the other child who is among the three youngest children since the position next to the block of two children is prohibited. 
$$\color{green}{\square \square} \blacksquare \square \square \square \square \square$$
$$\square \square \square \square \square \blacksquare \color{green}{\square \square}$$
There are $5!$ ways to arrange the five older children in the five remaining seats.  Hence, there are 
$$\binom{3}{2} \cdot 2 \cdot 2! \cdot 5 \cdot 5!$$
such arrangements.

*Exactly two of the three youngest children are together but not at the ends*:  There are $\binom{3}{2}$ ways to choose which two of the three youngest children are together.  There are five ways to choose their locations since the leftmost of the two children must sit in the second, third, fourth, fifth, or sixth position.  There are two ways to arrange the selected children within their block.  There are four ways to choose the position of the other child who is among the three youngest children since the two positions next to the block of two children are prohibited.
$$\blacksquare \color{green}{\square \square} \blacksquare \square \square \square \square$$

$$\square \blacksquare \color{green}{\square \square} \blacksquare \square \square \square$$

$$\square \square \blacksquare \color{green}{\square \square} \blacksquare \square \square$$

$$\square \square \square \blacksquare \color{green}{\square \square} \blacksquare \square$$

$$\square \square \square \square \blacksquare \color{green}{\square \square} \blacksquare$$

There are $5!$ to arrange the five older children in the five remaining seats.  Hence, there are 
$$\binom{3}{2} \cdot 5 \cdot 2! \cdot 4 \cdot 5!$$
such arrangements.

*Total*:  Adding these two cases yields 
\begin{align*}
\binom{3}{2} \cdot 2 \cdot 2! \cdot 5 \cdot 5! + \binom{3}{2} \cdot 5 \cdot 2! \cdot 4 \cdot 5! & = \binom{3}{2} \cdot 2! \cdot 5 \cdot (2 + 4) \cdot 5!\\
& = \binom{3}{2} \cdot 2! \cdot 5 \cdot 6 \cdot 5!\\ 
& = \binom{3}{2} \cdot 2! \cdot 5 \cdot 6!\\
& = 3 \cdot 2 \cdot 5 \cdot 6!
\end{align*}

Comment: Fantastic write up! The explanations are very clear and detailed, and I love the graphical illustration with the boxes. I didn't know that you could do something like that in $\LaTeX$.