# 5 boys 3 girls in row a such that not all girls together. Two different approaches give different solutions.

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

> **Question:** In how many ways $5$ boys and $3$ girls can be seated in a row so that all $3$ girls do not sit together?

**Attempt 1:**
Find all the possible ways (which is $8!$), and subtract the total number of ways that the 3 girls can sit together.

`G` = Girl, `B` = Boy

Number of ways in `GGG`  $ =3!$

Consider `(GGG)` as one unit. Then,

Number of ways in `(GGG)BBBBB` $= 6!$

Therefore,
total number of ways that the 3 girls can sit together $= 3! \times 6! = 4320$

Answer $= 8! - 4320 = 40320 - 4320 = 36000$

**Attempt 2:**
Place boys in by keeping gaps for girls such that a gap is smaller for all 3 girls.

`_ _ B _ _ B _ _ B _ _ B _ _ B _ _`

Each gap has space for two girls. Therefore, all $3$ girls cannot sit together. And now, we can assign the $3$ girl to $3$ spaces from the above $12$ spaces in the gaps.

Total number of ways that girls can choose spaces $= 12 \times 11 \times 10 = 1320$

Total number of ways that boys can sit $= 5! = 120 $

Answer $= 1320 \times 120 = 158400$

> Why we get two different answers to two approaches? I guess that the **Attempt 1** is correct; If so why **attempt 2** is wrong?

**Note**: By referring to following question I could get more understanding how to deal with the question: [In how many ways can 5 boys and 3 girls be seated in a row such that no two girls are together?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2484027/in-how-many-ways-can-5-boys-and-3-girls-be-seated-in-a-row-such-that-no-two-girl).
But I could not get what is wrong with my **attempt 2** by referring that. So please answer mainly focusing on how the **Attempt 2** become fail?

Comment: Could it be that in the 2nd attempt, placing `_ G B` is counted separately from placing `G _ B`, while they should be the same?

Comment: For the second one the required answer is $\left (\binom {6} {3} \times 3! \times 5! \right) + \left (\binom {6} {2} \times 2! \times 3! \times 5! \right) = 14400 + 21600 = 36000,$ same answer as the first one.

Comment: To find the above result try to think two kinds of arrangements. $(1)$ BGBGBGBB or equivalent where each girl is separated by a boy from the others and $(2)$ BGGBGBBB or equivalent where two girls are together and the other girl is separated from them by a boy.

Comment: @lulu Thank you for pointing the possible duplicate. But this question focus mainly on what is the wrong conclusions in Attempt 2 of approaching the problem. Therefore, I think this has not to be marked duplicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the second attempt, you say that there are $12\times 11\times 10$ ways for 3 girls to choose a space. However, there are two ways to place one girl between two boys: `B G _ B` and `B _ G B` (same goes for the edge cases on the left of the leftmost boy `_ _ B` and on the right of the rightmost boy `B _ _`). The calculation $12\times 11\times 10$ counts them separately, while for the context of this exercise, such placements should be considered the same: it's one girl between two boys (or, one girl next to a boy).

Answer (score 0):

In attempt 2, you are overcounting. For example, when two girls are in the first two positions, only $5$ (not $10$) seats remain for the last girl.

You should consider two cases: 1) 1 double and 1 single; 2) all single:

$$P(3,2){6\choose 1}{5\choose 1}+P(6,3)=180+120=300$$
Hence:
$$300*5!=300*120=36000.$$